# Entity Framework many to many relationship Question

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables:

```
-Users (UserId(pk), Email, Password)
-Roles (RoleId(pk), RoleDescription)
-UsersInRole (UserId(pk), RoleId(pk))
```

I defined the relationships  Users->UsersInRole and Roles->UsersInRole in the DB. When I created the edmx file in Visual Studio, it shows only two classes: Users and Roles joined by a many to many relationship (the UsersInRole table is not shown as a class I'm guessing because that table is there to break the many to many DB issue).

Now, I'm trying to define a method that given a role, it should return a list of users. This does not work:

```
public List<User> usersPerRole(string role)
    {
        return from u in entities.Roles where u.RoleID == role select u.Users.ToList();
    }
```

Can anyone out there give me an example of the correct way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coupling table "UsersInRole" (without any other than two foreign keys that together form the primary key of the table) will be translated into navigation properties on "both sides" of the foreighn keys. So in the user and in the role entity. In Users it will be User.RolesForThisUser and in Roles it will be Role.UsersWithThisRole. Adding any complemnetary column in the coupling table will result in a specific entity for that table and lossing the navigation properties as explained.

Now for your question yuo can simpy do:

```
public List<User> usersPerRole(string role)
{
 using(Entities context is new Entities())
 {
  return context.Role.FirstOrDefault<Role>(r => r.ID == role).Include("UsersInRole")
 }
}
```

Comment: Both answers were valid, Unfortunately I can only mark one as correct, if anyone out there has this issue, you can go with any of these alternatives.

Comment: @webyacusa: Thanx! @Ladislav: an honour to have my answer "preferred" above the answer of the infamous EF guru Ladislav Mrinka;)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this (I expect you have `Users` navigation property on `Role` entity):

```
public List<User> UsersPerRole(string role)
{
     return entities.Roles
                    .Where(r => r.RoleId == role)
                    .SelectMany(r => r.Users)
                    .ToList();
}
```

You can rewrite the same without lambdas:

```
public List<User> UsersPerRole(string role)
{
     return (from r in entities.Roles
             from u in r.Users
             where r.RoleId == role
             select u).ToList();
}
```